# Unique registration for new writers to sign up

Tags: user-registration

I want to be able to sign up writers by sending them an email with a unique registration url (that maybe is valid for only a limited time). Overall though, I don't want anyone to be able to register. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try Gravity Forms plugin